# leveldb thread safety: reading in one thread, writing through another

Tags: leveldb

I have created one DB instance and would like to use it from different threads: one for reading through an iterator and another for writing. Would that be thread-safe or do I need to protect the object with locks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that would be safe. What wouldn't be safe is to use same iterator in different threads.

Comment: We do this extensively at my company across thousands of threads across our servers, and it works flawlessly.